# How to phrase 'people have become acutely/increasingly aware of X'

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I'm trying to convey the idea that people's behavior on the Internet is a reflection of our increasing social self-awareness, almost like a communal entity.

For context, here is the paragraph I'm writing:

> Google is a black box that magically has all the answers to your
>   questions. Type in 'why are people stupid' and 'why are people so
>   !@#$ stupid' is the first result. Hey, Google is pretty smart, it
>   immediately gave me what I wanted. But Google is just a information
>   aggregator, how can it be "smart"? I believe the answer to that lies
>   in the nature of how information is disseminated on the Internet. "phrase goes here"

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? I mean, people cannot _become increasingly_ anything but _are becoming_ or _have become acutely aware_ of something is fine.

Comment: @terdon, why can people not become increasingly aware of something? That sounds perfectly fine to me…

Comment: I have trouble articulating my idea. My primary problem is saying what I want to say and connecting it to the paragraph. Just saying 'people have become culturally self-aware' is a meaningless statement.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet because _increasingly_ already implies a change over time. _Become increasingly aware_ sounds very strange to me. _Becoming increasingly_ sounds fine but if they have _become_ it, their awareness is no longer _increasing_.

Comment: @remyabel what is it that they have become aware of?

Comment: @terdon This self-awareness explains the nature of Google's search results.

Comment: @terdon, I see what you mean now. I thought you meant that it was the verb ‘become’ with the adverb ‘increasingly’ that didn’t work for you, and that ‘acutely’ worked better. Of course, “People become increasingly aware” needs a specific context to work (“Players become increasingly familiar with the scoring system as they work their way through the levels”, for example), but we agree, then, that for the asker’s context here, “People are becoming increasingly aware of how information [something]” is fine? Alternatively, “People have become (much) more aware of …”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes those sound fine to me. My problem was with _have become increasingly X_, I would not use an adverb with _have become_.

Comment: @terdon I apologize for the vague question. Can either of you post an answer to how I could phrase it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the sentence you posted in the comment, I would go for something like this:

> Web pages today are specifically engineered to take into account cultural and social changes.

If you want to focus on the increase in awareness, you could say

> People today are more aware of cultural and social changes and, consequently, web pages are specifically engineered to take this into account.

or

> People today are more aware of cultural and social changes and build webpages accordingly.

Comment: How does "People today are more aware of cultural and social changes and specially engineer their web pages in response." sound?

Comment: @remyabel see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Google users have created collective temporal intelligence. In other words a conglomeration of information that can be accessed in a timely manner.